# how to avoid concurrent modification exception in hashmap without using itr.remove()

Tags: java

Use case is a function(genLitCodes) which takes BuildParams as argument say pparams . 
pparams has multidimentional hashmap as lit (for lit codes).
In genLitCodes I need to iterate so am using itr.remove() to avoid concurrentmodification exception.

But problem arises when control return to calling function and lit are to use again. I am seeing 0 mapping once control comes back from genLitCodes(..). 
My code again uses same lit which are not available now.

Any suggestion to avoid concurrentmodificationException as well as retaining reference to lits
will be appreciated

sample code is below

public boolean func(HashMap> plits,....) {

```
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> llits = plits;
    //some code

                Iterator literator = llits.entrySet().iterator();
                while (literator.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) literator.next();
                 //  some code
                }
                //some code
                ***literator.remove();///to avoid concurrent modification exception***
            //some code
}
```

Comment: One of the only ways to remove things from a list you're currently iterating without using an iterator (for some reason?) would be to keep a list of indeces/keys/elements to remove, and then removing them after you're done iterating.

Comment: Pls post relevant code to better suggest

Comment: I have added some code to make problem better understand @ manjunath

Comment: why do you need to remove from the map anyway? can you describe an example of execution with the actual and desired results?

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully understand your question. Based on my assumption i have said , In genLitCodes method wants to iterate the code means it just called `itr.next()` instead of `itr.remove`. Remove normally used to remove the entry from hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

Use java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap